# Should diff return nothing after rsync?

Tags: backup, diff, rsync

I just created a backup with

```
rsync -av --delete projects/ /Volumes/daten/projects/
```

Afterwards I ran

```
diff -r projects/ /Volumes/daten/projects/
```

just to check if everything's fine expecting no output from diff. However, diff found a lot of differences. Does that mean rsync did not correctly sync my data?

**Update:** When rerunning rsync it seems fine, there is nothing to do for rsync:

```
$ rsync -av --delete projects/ /Volumes/daten/projects/
building file list ... done

sent 470414 bytes  received 20 bytes  188173.60 bytes/sec
total size is 295619054  speedup is 628.40
```

However, diff doesn't stop to generate output, as if there are lots of different files. Here is a small excerpt:

```
$ diff -r projects/ /Volumes/daten/projects/
diff -r projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_dep/debug/package_dependencies/dex-renamer-state.txt /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_dep/debug/package_dependencies/dex-renamer-state.txt
1c1
< #Sat Dec 08 16:17:41 CST 2018
---
> #Sun Nov 04 19:34:13 CET 2018
diff -r projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_1/dex-renamer-state.txt /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_1/dex-renamer-state.txt
1c1
< #Sat Dec 08 16:17:41 CST 2018
---
> #Sun Nov 04 19:34:14 CET 2018
diff -r projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_2/dex-renamer-state.txt /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_2/dex-renamer-state.txt
1c1
< #Sat Dec 08 16:17:41 CST 2018
---
> #Sun Nov 04 19:34:14 CET 2018
diff -r projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_3/dex-renamer-state.txt /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_3/dex-renamer-state.txt
1c1
< #Sat Dec 08 16:17:42 CST 2018
---
> #Sun Nov 04 19:34:14 CET 2018
diff -r projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_4/dex-renamer-state.txt /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_4/dex-renamer-state.txt
1c1
< #Sat Dec 08 16:17:42 CST 2018
---
> #Sun Nov 04 19:52:00 CET 2018
diff -r projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_5/dex-renamer-state.txt /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_5/dex-renamer-state.txt
1c1
< #Sat Dec 08 16:17:42 CST 2018
---
> #Sun Nov 04 19:34:14 CET 2018
diff -r projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_6/dex-renamer-state.txt /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_6/dex-renamer-state.txt
1c1
< #Sat Dec 08 16:17:42 CST 2018
---
> #Sun Nov 04 19:34:14 CET 2018
diff -r projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_7/dex-renamer-state.txt /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_7/dex-renamer-state.txt
1c1
< #Sat Dec 08 16:17:42 CST 2018
---
> #Sun Nov 04 19:34:14 CET 2018
diff -r projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_8/dex-renamer-state.txt /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_8/dex-renamer-state.txt
1c1
< #Sat Dec 08 16:17:42 CST 2018
---
> #Sun Nov 04 19:34:14 CET 2018
diff -r projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_9/dex-renamer-state.txt /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/ir_slices/debug/package_slice_9/dex-renamer-state.txt
1c1
< #Sat Dec 08 16:17:42 CST 2018
---
> #Sun Nov 04 19:34:14 CET 2018
diff -r projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/packageInstantRunResourcesDebug/tmp/debug/dex-renamer-state.txt /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/packageInstantRunResourcesDebug/tmp/debug/dex-renamer-state.txt
1c1
< #Sat Dec 08 16:17:34 CST 2018
---
> #Sun Nov 04 19:33:52 CET 2018
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-classes/debug/instant-run-bootstrap.jar and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-classes/debug/instant-run-bootstrap.jar differ
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/compat/R$color.class and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/compat/R$color.class differ
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/coreui/R$color.class and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/coreui/R$color.class differ
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/coreutils/R$color.class and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/coreutils/R$color.class differ
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/fragment/R$color.class and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/fragment/R$color.class differ
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/graphics/drawable/R$color.class and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/graphics/drawable/R$color.class differ
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/graphics/drawable/animated/R$color.class and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/graphics/drawable/animated/R$color.class differ
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/mediacompat/R$color.class and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/mediacompat/R$color.class differ
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/v4/R$color.class and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/v4/R$color.class differ
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim.class and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim.class differ
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/v7/appcompat/R$color.class and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/android/support/v7/appcompat/R$color.class differ
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/cyberdynesoftware/catclicker/R$attr.class and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/cyberdynesoftware/catclicker/R$attr.class differ
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/cyberdynesoftware/catclicker/R$bool.class and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/cyberdynesoftware/catclicker/R$bool.class differ
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/cyberdynesoftware/catclicker/R$dimen.class and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/cyberdynesoftware/catclicker/R$dimen.class differ
Binary files projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/cyberdynesoftware/catclicker/R$drawable.class and /Volumes/daten/projects/CatClicker/app/build/intermediates/incremental-verifier/debug/cyberdynesoftware/catclicker/R$drawable.class differ
```

Comment: Without any output from your commands we can only guess what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a lot of files are not seen as "different" by rsync. By default rsync only checks the file sizes and the last modification timestamps of the files. Please try using rsync with the `-c/--checksum` option to turn on checksumming and run "diff" again.

Excerpt from the rsync man page:

> -c, --checksum
>
> This  changes  the way rsync checks if the files have been changed and are in need of a transfer.  Without this option,
>                 rsync uses a "quick check" that (by default) checks if each file's size and time of last modification match between the
>                 sender  and  receiver.   This option changes this to compare a 128-bit checksum for each file that has a matching size.
>                 Generating the checksums means that both sides will expend a lot of disk I/O reading all the data in the files  in  the
>                 transfer  (and  this is prior to any reading that will be done to transfer changed files), so this can slow things down
>                 significantly.

Comment: "_It seems that a lot of files are not seen as "different" by rsync._" How can this happens in the OP example when rsync is supposed to also check the time of last modification? I mean, in which specific scenario(s) can this issue occur?